# Fields not being imported to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

I have an ELK instance that uses a redis channel as a buffer.  Logs are imported, correctly parsed into redis by the shipper but nothing makes it to elasticsearch.

My shipper config looks like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/var/log/aggregates.log" ]
    type => "aggregates"
  }
}

output {
  redis {
    host => "xxxx"
    data_type => "channel"
    key => "logstash-aggregates"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    columns => [ 'start_time', 'end_time','total_count' ... ] 
    separator => "," 
  }
}
```

The indexer config looks like this:

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "xxxx"
    type => "aggregates"
    data_type => "channel"
    key => "logstash-aggregates"
    format => "json_event"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    bind_host => "xxxx"
    cluster => "default_cluster"
    host => "xxxx"
    action => "index"
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?  I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Anything in the indexer log files, or the elasticsearch log files?  Try adding a stdout{} output on the indexer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Nothing exciting in the logs, running with stdout I see the following after an event comes through redis: `2015-08-27T20:28:33.581+0000 %{host} %{message}`

Comment: Try adding `--debug` on the logstash command-line to get more insights into what's happening.

Comment: Do you literally see "%{host}" and "%{message}"?

Comment: Yea, that's straight out of the console... strange.